# Mongodb + PHP => Find query operator in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

I need to find in array saved in a document of Mongodb.

Here is the document :

```
{

 "hashtag" : "World",
 "topimages" : [ 
        {
            "cluster" : "france",
            "id_tw" : "477170636327227393"
        },
        {
            "cluster" : "france",
            "id_tw" : "477170636327227396"
        }

  ]

}
```

And I want to search if a document named "World" by key "hashtag", have already a tweet saved in the array "topimages" with an id "id_tw" of value : "477170636327227393"

What I'm trying to do is :

```
$query = array('hashtag' => "World", array('topsimages.$.id_tw' => "477170636327227393"));
$xpmm->find($query);
```

I need to search if a document called "World" has already a tweet saved in the array "topimages" by his key "id_tw".

Thanks a lot.

#

Solution :

```
$query = array('hashtag' => "france", 'topimages.id_tw' => "477170282852286464");
```

Answer (score 0):

topimages.x would only work if it was a subdocument, not an array. You want `$elemMatch` ([Mongo DB Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/))

```
$query = array('hashtag' => "World", 'topsimages' => array("$elemMatch" => array("id_tw" => "477170636327227393")));
```

Comment: It doesn't work also with : `$query = array('hashtag' => "france", array('topimages' => array('$elemMatch' => array("id_tw" => "477170636327227393"))));`

Comment: Try again with code in answer. I added an extra array around topimages by mistake the first time.

Answer (score 0):

That's ok using :

```
$query = array('hashtag' => "france", 'topimages.id_tw' => "477170282852286464");
```